# Replace items in a list by for in statement ( Python)

Tags: python

I am a new Python user and I am wondering how to replace every integer in a list with str variables?

I used the for-in statement, but it is not working. Please let me know how I can make the code work? Thank you so much!

[my code (what is wrong here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m7PX.png)

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images

Comment: what you have shown in image is completely ambiguous with question that you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
int_list = [2, 33, 4, 55, 5, 56, 34, 6, 6, 76, 78657, 234, 3, 4]
New = []

for N in int_list:
    New.append(str(N) + ('small' if N < 30 else 'large'))
print(New)
```

Result:

```
['2small', '33large', '4small', '55large', '5small', '56large', '34large', '6small', '6small', '76large', '78657large', '234large', '3small', '4small']
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked! Much appreciated.